# Magento 2 custom theme based on parent Luma theme necessary files

Tags: magento2, theme, theme-fallback, luma-theme

I created my custom theme based on Magento Luma theme:

- In `/app/design/frontend/MyVendorName/ncs-theme/theme.xml` I added `<parent>Magento/luma</parent>`

But when I look at my frontend I see some differences. For example on the product-view page (see attachment), the structure of `<div class="product-info-price">` is different then the Luma theme?
[image]

And on the homepage it's also missing **styles** for the `<div class="content-heading">` (see image). Do I have to copy some files into my custom theme?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the commmand line tool to regenerate the static files and the cache.

I would also try running your server as an administrator so that it doesn't have any issues with symlinks.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli.html

Comment: 1) I am using MAMP for local development. How do run my server as an administrator? 2) My mode is 'development', before I already did `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and cleared cash?

Comment: Setup:static-content:deploy is useless and takes too long.

Comment: Install grunt, it works much better.

Mac OS complicates this for me, I would try this on my mac:
http://osxdaily.com/2013/02/06/how-to-run-gui-apps-as-root-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: Ok I will install Grunt. Thanks. But regarding my first image. What is missing here? If I look in `/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`. I see Luma theme is changing the HTML structure here. But why it's not visible on my frontend, while Luma is my parent theme and my custom theme should inherit everything from Luma theme isn't it?

Comment: If Luma is your parent theme but you are replacing that file with another correctly, it should ignore that file and use yours instead.

Comment: But do I have to replace it to my custom theme folder? I am not going to **change** that file... If I am not going to change it, why should I copy it over?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you were trying to change it.

You're saying the file says X and the result is instead Y.

Is the theme applied through admin? (I assume yes, but have to check)


If it is applied through admin, then it is either a static file issue where they need deleting (grunt or can be done manually) or a symlink (administrator/superuser) issue.

Comment: What do you mean with 'Is the theme applied through admin', like I did explained below? I setup my custom theme like [explained here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html) and then I by `admin/system_config/edit/section/design`

Comment: Change the theme to blank and back?

Comment: is it possible to use Luma as parent theme without issues? And how?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the registration.php file too? That is also the required file to be added in new custom theme. If you are facing product view related issues then you can also put the file etc/view.xml from luma to your custom theme. Custom theme requires two files be added always:

1. Registration.php

   `<?php 
     \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
       \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
       'frontend/{{vendor}}/{{theme}}',
       __DIR__
     );`
2. Theme.xml

   `<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
   <title>Your Theme</title>
   <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
   <media>
       <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
   </media>
   </theme>`
3. etc/view.xml (optional) : if you set blank theme as parent then you need to add this, however, I would suggest to add this file too in case you are facing issues to display product data with luma as parent. You can simply copy it from luma to your custom theme.