# Customize Magento 2 Blank theme

Tags: magento2, theme, less, luma-theme

I have setup my custom theme and using Magento 2 Blank theme as the parent theme `<parent>Magento/blank</parent>`

1. I like the Luma icons more. How do I add the Luma icons in my custom theme?
2. The Luma homepage have styles for the `content-heading`. Where/in
   which less file are those styles added in the Luma theme? And what
   are best practices to add those to my own custom theme?
3. I want to style the wishlist, compare and email links (below tocart
   button) on the productview page exactly like Luma theme. I see in
   `/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/_module.less‌`​
   those styles. Do I have to copy those styles over to
   /app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/source/_theme.less? Or is
   there a better/other preferred way to do it?
4. I want to style the tabs on the productview page exactly like Luma
   theme. So it has a border around it? Where are those less styles in
   Luma theme and where do I have to add those styles?

**Update:**

1. If you look at Luma's `<div class="panel wrapper">`, they added a
   background-color. What is the preferred way to add this class and
   it's variable to my custom theme? (I know in Luma theme it's living
   in
   `/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less`.
   But how do I get this in my own theme? What is the preferred
   workflow?

Answer (score 1):

Look at `vendor/magento/theme-fronted-luma/web/css/source/_theme.less` (line 19-20) and you will find:

```
@icons__font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/Luma-Icons';
@icons__font-name: 'luma-icons';
```

inside `vendor/magento/theme-fronted-luma/web` you will also find the fonts dir. Try to copy the font dir in the appropriate dir inside your custom theme and change the 2 less variables.

Comment: I tried above method already. But then the icons are too large everywhere? The font-size is then 35px. In Luma it's 22px for all the icons and the `line-height: 28px;`. How do I fix this? But what about [this approach](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/using-fonts.html)? And what about my second question about `content-heading` styles?

Comment: You can always add some css to fix icons size. About `content-heading` i didn't find any reference inside luma theme, maybe it comes with sample data

Comment: Thanks. I am a bit lost in what is best way customizing blank theme. **Example 1:** I want to style the wishlist, compare and email links (below tocart button) on the productview page exactly like Luma theme. I see in `/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/_module.less` those styles. Do I have to copy those styles over to `/app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/source/_theme.less`? Or is there a better/other preferred way to do it? **Example 2:** I want to style the tabs on the productview page exactly like Luma theme. So it has a border around it?

Comment: but if you want to style blank like luma theme, why don't you start with luma directly? (luma is based on blank however)

Comment: Thats what I tried but I get issues when use luma as parent theme like I [described here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119532/magento-2-custom-theme-based-on-parent-luma-theme-necessary-files). If it's possible I definitely want to use Luma as parent theme! But why do I have those issues? I didn't find a solution yet... Thanks

Comment: I see, i'm sorry that i can't help, but m2 frontend is such a mess!

Comment: I updated my question (because I am a bit lost in Magento 2 custom theme design workflow)...